# "git apply" gives error "does not match index" when a previous apply skips hunks

Tags: git, git-apply

git version 2.19.0

I have two commits for file 'myfile' I am cherry picking from one branch to another branch.  During the last patch apply, I get "error: mydir/myfile: does not match index".

1) I generate the two patch files commit1.patch (oldest) and commit2.patch (newest):

```
cd /target-branch  
git --git-dir=/source-branch/myrepo/.git format-patch -k -1 <commit N's ID>
```

2) I apply patch #1:

```
git apply -3 commit1.patch  
error: patch failed: mydir/myfile:17  
error: repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge.
error: mydir/myfile: patch does not apply
```

...which fails as expected because two of the hunks in patch modify code blocks added in a commit older than commit #1.  I'm not applying that older commit because it's a fix I do not want in target branch.

3) I reapply patch 1 using --reject instead of -3 to skip applying the two non-applicable hunks:

```
git apply --reject 1.patch
```

... which logs no errors and logs the two patch hunks it skipped as expected, and applies the rest of the patch.

4) I apply patch #2:

```
git apply -3 commit2.patch
error: mydir/myfile: does not match index
```

**Why error "does not match index"?**  'git status' shows staging is empty, 'git fsck' reports no errors, 'git diff --cached' reports nothing.

I found a workaround: Fresh clone the target branch, edit-out the two hunks which cannot be applied from commit1.patch, then do:

```
git apply -3 commit1.patch
git apply -3 commit2.patch
```

… which works with no errors

How can I resolve the "does not match index" error commit2.patch outputs, other than first manually removing the two hunks from commit1.patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your issue is in [the `git apply` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply), but in several parts, to which I added boldface (the options were already boldfaced):

> **-3, --3way**
>    When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge if
>    the patch records the identity of blobs it is supposed to apply to,
>    and we have those blobs available locally, possibly leaving the
>    conflict markers in the files in the working tree for the user to
>    resolve. **This option implies the `--index` option**, and is
>    incompatible with the `--reject` and the `--cached` options.

From here you must back up a bit:

> **--index**
>    When `--check` is in effect, or when applying the patch (which is the
>    default when none of the options that disables it is in effect),
>    make sure the patch is applicable to what the current index file
>    records. **If the file to be patched in the working tree is not up to
>    date, it is flagged as an error.** This flag also causes the index
>    file to be updated.

So by using `-3` you turned on `--index`, and `--index` explicitly calls for an error if the work-tree copy of the file does not match the index copy of the file.

Earlier, in step 3, you manually ran `git apply --reject`, *without* `-3` or `--index`.  That *doesn't* fail when creating the `.rej` file, but *does* leave the index and work-tree copies different.

If there is to be no point in using `-3`, simply leave it out in both cases, so that you apply without updating the index copy of the file and without constraining the work-tree copy of the file to *match* the index copy of the file either.

Comment: Thank you!  Using your advice I started clean and ran "git apply --reject commit1.patch", then "git apply commit2.patch".  Finished with no errors and skipped two hunks in patch 1 as expected.